# Hosting servers: Listing all folders and files in certain directory on the screen

Tags: php, list, hosting, server

When I enter url, for example `ignasdamunskis.lt/sites`, I want all the items in the `sites` directory to be listed on the screen.

Is it possible without me listing them by hand? Is it secure for my website?

Comment: Usually `mod_index` handles that already. What's your actual issue? (The broad inquiry about security implications cannot be answered here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the folder, add a file named `.htaccess` containing the following:

`Options +Indexes`

This assumes your hosting allows such on-the-fly configuration.

Is it secure? Well, that depends on what's in the folder!

Comment: It's only sites folders for portfolio, nothing more actually

Comment: Then there should be no issues, as long as it stays that way.